# How to pass numerous arguments to a BackgroundWorker in c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, backgroundworker

I've seen examples of this in C# and VB, but i'm really constrained to c++, I'm trying to pass 20 Strings to a background worker so that it can perform a task on them. I've tried passing the windows form object, but it can't be casted back to a Form from a System::Object without causing compiler errors.

I've also tried passing an object which contains the strings through the DoWork  method, however this also doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Can you give the specifics (and possibly code) of why the object-contained strings did not work?

Answer (score 0):

For a larger number of strings (or, more generally, "tasks"), you would either use a synchronized queue, a lockfree queue, or as the easiest solution, a completion port. Completion ports are surprisingly efficient, if you have no more than a few ten thousand tasks to schedule, it really isn't worth thinking about a more sophisticated solution.

For only 20 tasks, this is usually overkill (unless each task runs for a very long time), putting everthing into one object and passing a pointer to that object is the best solution. Otherwise, the communication/synchronisation overhead is more than the gain from multithreading.

Passing a pointer to a struct to a worker thread should work perfectly fine in C++ (I'm doing that all the time). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I've tried using a struct and passing a pointer to it, however, when defining the struct in a header file, I always receive the compile error 


error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'length' in an unmanaged 'data'  may not declare a global or static variable, or a member of a native type that refers to objects in the gc heap

`using namespace System;



struct data
{

  static String^ length;
  static String^ width;
  
  
};`

Comment: Um... you said you're constrained to C++, and tagged your question as "C++" too. This is C# code you're posting, I'm surprised that gives not more errors. Try something like struct data { std::string* a; std::string b; }; and pass data* to your thread function.

Comment: Ok, so it's still broke, apart from the pain of converting a System String to a char array, the compiler still complains about not being able to convert from a System::Object^

`data *passvars;
passvars->a = (const char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Form1::moduleLength->Text).ToPointer());
passvars->b = (const char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Form1::moduleWidth->Text).ToPointer());
backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync( passvars );
`

Comment: You still seem to mix up things. For example, there is no notion of what you try to do wiht Object^ in C++. Operator^ means "exclusive or", so above line makes no sense. There is no such thing as xor between a type and a variable. You would need something similar to: struct data { const char* a; /* plus any other fields */ }; data *p = new data; p->a = (const char*) (... /* whatever*/); bgworker->RunWorkerAsync(p); Note that using C casts in C++ like this is frowned upon, and also note that you must remember to free the memory (or this will leak).